# Unable to access WORKSPACE inside Jenkinsfile pipelines.agent.dockerfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to mount the workspace as a volume when using Jenkinsfile, but am getting an error that WORKSPACE does not exist as a binding.

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    dockerfile {
      filename 'Dockerfile'
      dir 'docker/build_env'
      args "-v ${WORKSPACE}/source:/slate/source -v ${WORKSPACE}/build:/slate/build"
    }
  }
}
```

And the error is:

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: WORKSPACE for class: groovy.lang.Binding

I've also tried ${env.WORKSPACE} but this resolves as null and pwd() which resolved to a class name. I've previously used ${WORKSPACE} successfully before so I'm at a loss.

Please can someone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried ${workspace}?

Comment: `${env.WORKSPACE}` should be the correct reference, so there must be something deeper going on if that is not working for you.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is quotation marks. "-v ${WORKSPACE}/source:/slate/source -v ${WORKSPACE}/build:/slate/build" should be '-v ${WORKSPACE}/source:/slate/source -v ${WORKSPACE}/build:/slate/build'